# Getting error when trying to deploy java spring app to Oracle web-logic cluster java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52304

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, javabeans, weblogic12c

Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error when trying to deploy my Java-8 with spring 3.1.2 app on Oracle Weblogic 12c Cluster.
Build and unit test are successful on my local machine. I am using Jenkins Pipeline to deploy and that is where I get an exception error.

> Target state: deploy failed on Cluster XYZCluster
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52304

```
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)

at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)

at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)

at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)

at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:70)

at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)

at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)

at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)

at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:660)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1974)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1951)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1841)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2891)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)

at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)

at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)

at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)

at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)

at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)

at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)

at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)

at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)

at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)

at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)

at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)

at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)

at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)

at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)

at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)

at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)

at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)

at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)

at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)

at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having this error because spring version 3.1.2 is not working fine with Java 8, due to the introduction of new Java features in this version (Like lambda expressions).

For solve the problem you have to upgrade to a Spring version >= 4.